# How to hide a language code from specific page in Polylang plugin

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, polylang

I am working on WordPress website in which I am using multilingual functionality.
and I am using POLYLANG plugin.

I have a situation in which , I have to remove
language code from URL , for **SPECIFIC PAGES** only
this is how URL generates :  `site_url/nl/page_slug`

and I want to create URL like this `site_url/page_slug`

So , for some of the pages I want to remove `nl`

How do I make it happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the below filter and the issue was resolved.

```
function filter_pll_check_canonical_url( $redirect_url, $language ) {
   $redirect_url = str_replace('nl', '', $redirect_url);
}
add_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', 'filter_pll_check_canonical_url', 10, 2 );
```

I am checking with the current URL, if the current URL has a language code so replaced language code with a blank space and URL will seem to like:-

```
site_url/nl/page_slug => site_url/page_slug
```

Comment: Hi, I have similar task -   hide a language code from specific page.... but dont understand where you add the url of the page for which you want to hide the code....

Comment: I have simply added above snippet in the functions.php file and checked the url "$redirect_url" variable with function argument and there is getting url with language slug so I have replaced language slug with blank space and it's work for me.